# Cordova Geolocation Example Not Working

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

I am trying to get the following Cordova Geoplocation example (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/#find-stores-near-you) to work but no HTML is provided. In short, I need the app to get the user's current location as well as list nearby restaurants. I tried improvising by using  as is generally used in examples using the Google Places API, but no luck. I'm not getting an error messages in the console.

The output I do get is:

navigator.geolocation works well

45.5039025 -73.5639405

My code:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #map{height:100%; width:100%;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATmobTWsilWKnIIhYzzHbjT6WEQp8K7kc&libraries&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
        var Map;
        var Infowindow;
        var Latitude = undefined;
        var Longitude = undefined;

        // Get geo coordinates
        function getPlacesLocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
            (onPlacesSuccess, onPlacesError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
        }

        // Success callback for get geo coordinates
        var onPlacesSuccess = function (position) {
            Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            console.log(Latitude + " " + Longitude);
        }

        // Get places by using coordinates
        function getPlaces(latitude, longitude) {
            console.log("Here");
            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("places"), mapOptions);
            Infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(Map);
            service.nearbySearch({
                location:latLong,
                radius:1500,
                type:['restaurant']
            }, foundStoresCallback);
        }

        // Success callback for watching your changing position
        var onPlacesWatchSuccess = function (position) {
            var updatedLatitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var updatedLongitude = position.coords.longitude;

            if (updatedLatitude != Latitude && updatedLongitude != Longitude) {
                Latitude = updatedLatitude;
                Longitude = updatedLongitude;
                getPlaces(updatedLatitude, updatedLongitude);
            }
        }

        // Success callback for locating stores in the area
        function foundStoresCallback(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        // Place a pin for each store on the map
        function createMarker(place) {
            var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: Map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                Infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                Infowindow.open(Map, this);
            });
        }

        // Error callback
        function onPlacesError(error) {
            console.log('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Watch your changing position
        function watchPlacesPosition() {
            return navigator.geolocation.watchPosition
            (onPlacesWatchSuccess, onPlacesError, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="menu" class="menu">
        <div data-bind="with: selectedLanguage">
            <a href="index.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span data-bind="text:home" class="menu-header-title">Home</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="upcoming_plates.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span data-bind="text:upcoming" class="menu-header-title">Upcoming Plates</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="previous_plates.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Previous Plates</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="notifications.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Notifications</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="preferences.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Preferences</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="invite.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Invite</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="feature_my_restaurant.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Feature My Restaurant</span>
                </header>
            </a>
            <a href="account_settings.html">
                <header class="menu-header">
                    <span class="menu-header-title">Account Settings</span>
                </header>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main id="panel" class="panel">
        <header class="panel-header">
            <button class="btn-hamburger js-slideout-toggle"></button>
            <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
            <select data-bind="options:languages, optionsText:'name', value:selectedLanguage"></select>
        </header>
        <section class="box">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </section>
        <!--
        <footer class="panel-footer">
            <p>with <span class="heart">❤</span> by <a href="https://getmango.com/en" target="_blank">Mango</a></p>
        </footer>
        -->
    </main>
    <script src="dist/slideout.js"></script>
    <script src="js/languages.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {

        var Language = function (language) {
            this.name = language.name;
            this.home = language.home;
            this.upcoming = language.upcoming;
            //this.header = language.header;
            //this.subHeader = language.subHeader;
            //this.body =language.body;
        };

        var ViewModel = function (data) {
            var self = this;
            self.languages = ko.observableArray(
            ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (i) {
                return new Language(i);
            }));
            self.selectedLanguage = ko.observable();
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(languages));

        var slideout = new Slideout({
            'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
            'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
            'side': 'right'
        });

        document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function() {
            slideout.toggle();
        });

        document.querySelector('.menu').addEventListener('click', function(eve) {
            if (eve.target.nodeName === 'A'){slideout.close();}});
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            getPlacesLocation();
            console.log("navigator.geolocation works well");
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is this being down voted...?

Comment: Hi. Have you install the plugin-geolocation with: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation` ? How did you add cordova to your project? You have followed these steps? [cordova getstarted](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted)

Comment: Yes, i installed both plugins. I found my error. I was that I need the following HTML:
<div id="map"></div> although when I tried it originally it didn't work... possibly conflicts with other JS.

Answer (score 0):

Add an empty div with an id of "map" to run the example (NOT shown on Cordova web site!).